# CAEmitterLayer not rendering when -renderInContext: of superlayer is called

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, caemitterlayer

I have a drawing app and I would like for my users to be able to use particle effects as part of their drawing. Basically, the point of the app is to perform custom drawing and save to Camera Roll or share over the World Wide Web.

I encounted the `CAEmitterLayer` class recently, which I reckon would be a simple and effective way to add particle effects.

I have been able to draw the particles onscreen in the app using the `CAEmitterLayer` implementation. So rendering onscreen works fine.

When I go about rendering the contents of the drawing using

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithSize(self.bounds.size);

// The instance drawingView has a CAEmitterLayer instance in its layer/view hierarchy
[drawingView.layer renderInContext:context];


//Note: I have also tried using the layer.presentationLayer and still nada

....
//Get the image from the current image context here for saving to Camera Roll or sharing


....the particles are never rendered in the image.
```

What I think is happening

The `CAEmitterLayer` is in a constant state of "animating" the particles. That's why when I attempt to render the layer (I have also tried render the `layers.presentationLayer` and modelLayer), the animations are never committed and so the off screen image render does not contain the particles.

Question
Has anyone rendered the contents of a `CAEmitterLayer` offscreen? If so, how did you do it?

Alternate Question
Does anyone know of any particle effect system libraries that don't use OpenGL and is not Cocos2D?

Comment: Nope, see Revis answer below. CAEmitterLayer can't call renderInContext:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-[CALayer renderInContext:]` is useful in a few simple cases, but will not work as expected in more complicated situations. You will need to find some other way to do your drawing.

[The documentation for `-[CALayer renderInContext:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW120) says:

> The Mac OS X v10.5 implementation of this method does not
>   support the entire Core Animation composition model.
>   QCCompositionLayer, CAOpenGLLayer, and QTMovieLayer layers are not
>   rendered. Additionally, layers that use 3D transforms are not
>   rendered, nor are layers that specify backgroundFilters, filters,
>   compositingFilter, or a mask values. Future versions of Mac OS X may
>   add support for rendering these layers and properties.

(These limitations apply to iOS, too.)

The header `CALayer.h` also says:

```
 * WARNING: currently this method does not implement the full
 * CoreAnimation composition model, use with caution. */
```

Comment: Nicely stated! Other people want to do this, there is some undocumented way to grab the pixels but of course you could never use it in a submitted app. I wonder if you could somehow add a similar layer to a bitmap context, and then grab that? It would not be what the user saw but maybe you could get something similar?

Comment: Do you know any undocumented way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my CAEmitterLayer rendered as an image correctly in its current animation state with

```
Swift

func drawViewHierarchyInRect(_ rect: CGRect,
          afterScreenUpdates afterUpdates: Bool) -> Bool



Objective-C

- (BOOL)drawViewHierarchyInRect:(CGRect)rect
             afterScreenUpdates:(BOOL)afterUpdates
```

within a current context

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
```

and set afterScreenUpdates to true|YES

Good luck with that one :D

Comment: We can use this but CAEmitterLayer will become slow from second screenshot  .