# Screenshot View with CAEmitterLayer

Tags: swift, caemitterlayer

Is it possible to take a screenshot of a view that includes a CAEmitterLayer?

Whenever I try, the view is created fine, but all of the particles are missing, here's my code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawingView.frame.size)
var context:CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
drawingView.layer.renderInContext(context)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
return image
```

I have confirmed that the CAEmitterLayer is on the drawingView.layer

Comment: Finally, I get something using: drawViewHierarchyInRect, this post talks about CAEmitterLayer not being able to be drawn at renderInContext http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926690/caemitterlayer-not-rendering-when-renderincontext-of-superlayer-is-called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for iOS, but now I need a similar method for OSX:

```
func offscreenScreenshot(drawingView:UIView) -> Image
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(drawingView.frame.size, true, 1.0)
    let res = drawingView.drawViewHierarchyInRect(drawingView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris,I tried the code but i ma facing issue with image quality and missing snapshot data,Could please suggest for the solution..?

Comment: Is it a scale issue? if so, set 1.0 to 0 for the scale parameter.

Comment: and also missing snapshot data because of  afterScreenUpdates: false.if i set afterScreenUpdates: true  UIView was blink and then updated

Comment: I think you might need to post some code, maybe a new SO question

Comment: can you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42918044/issue-with-drawviewhierarchyinrect-afterscreenupdates-while-taking-snapshot