# Issue With drawViewHierarchyInRect: afterScreenUpdates while taking snapshot

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimage, uigraphicscontext

I am facing problem with taking snapshot of `UIView` along with `CAEmitterLayer`. Below is the code which I am using for taking snapshot:

here `editingView` is my `UIView`:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(editingView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
[editingView drawViewHierarchyInRect:editingView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Please go through the below links for Gif Images

Link For [For afterScreenUpdates:NO](http://makeagif.com/i/HmtTJA) (Gif) in this case I am missing Snapshot data

Link For [For afterScreenUpdates:YES](http://makeagif.com/i/kafV69) (Gif) in this case uiview is blinking and then updated and also facing performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar a similar issue in the past. The following might work for you as a workaround:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(editingView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
[editingView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Note that you may lose some accuracy in the screen capture, as it may exclude blurs, and some Core Animation features.

**Edit:**

There seems to be issues/tradeoffs with both `renderInContext` and `drawViewHierarchyInRect`. The following code may be worth a try (taken from [here](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673) for reference):

```
- (CGContextRef) createBitmapContextOfSize:(CGSize) size {
   CGContextRef    context = NULL;
   CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
   int             bitmapByteCount;
   int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

   bitmapBytesPerRow   = (size.width * 4);
   bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * size.height);
   colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
   if (bitmapData != NULL) {
       free(bitmapData);
   }
   bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
   if (bitmapData == NULL) {
       fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
       return NULL;
   }

   context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                    size.width,
                                    size.height,
                                    8,      // bits per component
                                    bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                    colorSpace,
                                    kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);

   CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context,NO);
   if (context== NULL) {
       free (bitmapData);
       fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
       return NULL;
   }
   CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );

   CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, size.height);
   CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);

   return context;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
CGContextRef context = [self createBitmapContextOfSize:editingView.bounds.size];
[editingView.layer renderInContext:context];

CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
UIImage* background = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: cgImage];
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
```

Comment: Hi Allan Poole, I tried this. but i am failed to get snap shot for CAEmitterLayer along with UIView. for this I found something related Core Animations can you refer this link for  quick idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926690/caemitterlayer-not-rendering-when-renderincontext-of-superlayer-is-called. and please help me regarding this.And please go through with gif links which i provided

Comment: There seems to be issues/trade offs with both solutions. I've updated my answer with a possible alternative. The code is from a fairly old article, so it may or may not work.